# Memcached extension for PHP on Windows Server

Tags: php, windows, memcached

Windows 2008
IIS 7
PHP 5.2.10 / FastCGI
Memcache as a Windows Service
I tried to use the php_memcache extension for PHP but it doesn't load. This extension comes with PECL 5.2.6

Any idea? Do you know if exist a php_memcache"d" extension for PHP on Windows?

BR Santiago

Answer (score 2):

Wbdvlpr - you've missed the emphasis the original poster put on the fact they are looking for php_memcached.dll, not php_memcache.dll

Web searches for php_memcached.dll mostly do seem to lead to php_memcache.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded memcached from http://splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/

and started it like memcached.exe -d install

then took the php_memcache.dll vc9 version from downloads.php.net/pierre/ not the vts one

unpacked to php's extension folder,

restarted apache, and made sure
with phpinfo() that it works.

Comment: Again, this is not memcached.